# Cannot set appropriate permissions to avoid 403 error

Tags: permissions, cifs

Excuse me, I know there are many questions similar to this one, but I wasn't able to solve the problem. My primary problem is that I cannot access my own web page because of "403 Forbidden" error. I thought that it will be some trivial problem but I have spent two days looking for solution. I will describe my steps which are based on several internet discussions, but I don't understand many of the words I am going to use :)

I thought that the problem is that the permissions to, say, index.html, are not set properly, but maybe the reason is completely different. Nevertheless, I wanted to change the permissions but was not able to.

So, my web page is located on the network disk of our department. I mount this disk using fstab:

```
//utf/scholtz /home/scholtz/troja-scholtz cifs  uid=1000,username=scholtz 0 0
```

Now I can freely modify/create files on the mounted disk. When I use `ls -l`, I find

```
-rw-r-----. 1 scholtz 1012  5160 Sep 13 17:41 index.html
```

I tried to type

```
chmod 664 index.html
```

but nothing changed.

On several discussion fora I discovered the possibility of the modification of the fstab command:

```
//utf/scholtz /home/scholtz/troja-scholtz cifs  uid=1000,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0664,username=scholtz 0 0
```

I am not sure what that should mean exactly, but the result was the same. I also found something about "umask" but didn't understand what it means.

Can anybody help me, please?